# How do I setup/launch Sidekiq (or Resque) on a Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, jruby, resque, sidekiq, jrubyonrails

I'm playing around with JRuby on Rails and want to use Sidekiq (or Resque) as part of a stack I'm building. Things work well locally, but I'm stumbling to find a way to boostrap a Sidekiq server within the production environment (I'm using a Bitnami JRuby AMI for now: https://bitnami.com/stack/jruby). Can anyone comment on how to set this up? More generally, how does one install/run system processes?

One thing I've considered is setting up Sidekiq as a standalone .war file and deploying that alongside my main application...but I haven't investigated that yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the Bitnami stack uses in detail, but if it's recent Warbler + JRuby-Rack than one option that might work is setting up [JRuby-Rack-Worker](https://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker) :

1. a thread-safe worker on top of e.g. Resque (Sidekiq is not provided out of the box) ... here I'm not sure if it will work with recent Resuqe - depends on how much their internals have changed
2. configure Warbler to include a context-listener to bootstrap the worker (see the README)